# Sending large json data to breezecontroller fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using breezejs to handle my entities on a web application.

Specifically i start with the Angular HotTowel template.

The problem i'm having is that i'm sending a large json array of objects (length about 17000) so on my controller im getting null on the parameter to receive this information.

When I try to send less data an array of 5000 objects then the controller parameter is setted with the objects correctlly.

My controller

```
[BreezeController]
public class SoftProductsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly EFContextProvider<Context> contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<Context>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return this.contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        //Here saveBundle is NULL
        return this.contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);

    }
}
```

Could be this related to some json deserialization on WebApi when using large json data?

I tried setting this option on the web.congif with no success

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="20000"/>
</appSettings>
```

I'm using .NET 4.5

Any idea?

Comment: Holy smokes! That's a lot of data. I have no idea who is refusing it or why. But I sure am curious how you built a save bundle with 17,000 objects.

Comment: @Ward thanks for your curiousity :) I'm building a first proof of concept of a .csv file importer. Right now the focus is on make it work with raw with a chunk of data and later on improve it. :)

Comment: OK. I'm pretty sure I wouldn't use Breeze for this part. I'd be looking for the fastest and most efficient method to pump that stuff up to the server. I think of Breeze as a tool for humans who are *working* with a set of data for some period of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was the default limit on requestLenght that ASP.NET have.
Increasing that limit on the web.config allow breeze to post large data.
(default size is 4096 KB)

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="5120" />
</system.web>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx